# Changing \leftmargin in \enumerate based on width of largest label

Tags: enumerate

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=1.5cm, font=\bfseries, labelsep=1em]
    \item[1-1.*] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut 
    purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur 
    dictum gravida mauris. 
    \item[1-2.] Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,
    magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellen- tesque habitant morbi tristique 
    senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras 
    viverra metus rhoncus sem. 
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=1.5cm, label=(\alph*)]
        \item Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu 
    tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat.
        \item Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. 
    Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. 
    \end{enumerate}
    \item[1-12.*] Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, 
    nulla. Curabitur auc- tor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to make it so that everything is aligned like it is, but the largest number (in this case, 1-12.*) is flush left with the margin and everything else is aligned based on that. I also want to be able to indent the sublist (a), (b), etc. starting from the beginning of the text (not the numbers) in the main list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution, which uses the `widest=` key, from `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[widest=\bfseries1-12.*, labelindent =-0.333em, font=\bfseries, labelsep = 1em, leftmargin = *]
  \item[1-1.*] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut
        purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
        dictum gravida mauris.
  \item[1-2.\hphantom{*}] Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,
        magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellen- tesque habitant morbi tristique
        senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras
        viverra metus rhoncus sem.
        \begin{enumerate}[wide = 0pt, align = left, label=(\alph*), leftmargin=*]%leftmargin=2em
          \item Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu
                tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat.
          \item Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc.
                Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus.
        \end{enumerate}
  \item[1-12.*] Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac,
        nulla. Curabitur auc- tor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you make the numbers aligned right (with the text)? Only the widest label should be touching the left margin.

Comment: I changed the code for that. See my updated answer. Is that OK?

Comment: Perfect. Any thoughts on how to indent the sublist from the beginning of the text (e.g., so that the distance from the f in "fames" to (a) is \parindent)?

Comment: Please see the result of ‘my thoughts’ in the updated again answer.

Comment: Looks good, appreciate your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to give a hand.

Comment: maybe i'm too fussy, but i think this would look even nicer if the final period of the item labels were all in a line.  for "1.2." that would mean leaving a phantom space for the asterisk.

Comment: Would you be some *Little Miss Fussy* ? ;o) You're right, I'll change that in  a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you want to type in arbitrary labels for your first level, you may be better of using description lists (use calc package and enter the longest label into the description list options).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[leftmargin=!,labelwidth=\widthof{\bfseries 1-12.*}]
    \item[1-1.*] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut 
    purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur 
    dictum gravida mauris. 
    \item[1-2.] Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,
    magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellen- tesque habitant morbi tristique 
    senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras 
    viverra metus rhoncus sem. 
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
        \item Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu 
    tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat.
        \item Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. 
    Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. 
    \end{enumerate}
    \item[1-12.*] Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, 
    nulla. Curabitur auc- tor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That would be fine if you can fix the alignment. The labels should be flush right with the text.